# htaccess html5 history api - redirect to root folder works only without hash in route

Tags: .htaccess, html5-history

i've configured my htaccess file for html5 history api using Navigo like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

It works fine as long if i use this pattern :

```
mydomain.com/myroute
```

but - if add a **hash** to the route like this:

```
mydomain.com/myroute/
```

redirect to index.html is working, but **css und javascript** is not loaded, because index tries to load stylesheet and script from a subfolder "myroute/" which of course does not exist.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is: embed scripts with a leading hash:

```
src="/style.css"
```

instead of

```
src="style.css"
```

sometimes it's easy :)